# apt-get install problem

Tags: apt

I am trying to install

```
sudo apt-get install hal
```

But I get this error

> ubuntu dpkg was interrupted, you must manually run 'sudo dpkg --configure -a' to correct the problem.

I get this error now with any `sudo apt-get install` I try.

When i try

```
sudo dpkg --configure -a
```

I get

```
sudo dpkg --configure -a
Setting up storagemadeeasy (4.0-1) ...
Archive:  /usr/share/sme_install/Unix-Mknod-0.04.zip
replace /usr/share/sme_install/Unix-Mknod-0.04/typemap? [y]es, [n]o, [A]ll, [N]one.  [r]ename:
```

Then i don't know what to rename it to?

Comment: So... what happens when you run `sudo dpkg --configure -a`?

Comment: Sorry i get sudo dpkg --configure -a
Setting up storagemadeeasy (4.0-1) ...
Archive:  /usr/share/sme_install/Unix-Mknod-0.04.zip
replace /usr/share/sme_install/Unix-Mknod-0.04/typemap? [y]es, [n]o, [A]ll, [N]one, [r]ename:

Comment: Just type `y` and press `Enter`.

Comment: @green7 Agreed. The problem seems to come down to correct use of that command. I recommend expanding your comment slightly into an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just replace the file by typing `y` and then `Enter`.

The message you get asks you to replace an already existing file. You can just go on replacing it as it is very unlikely to cause any problems.

Comment: I did what you said and now I get the following error:

root@HAL9000:/home/feuergeist# sudo apt-get install bygfoot
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Package bygfoot is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'bygfoot' has no installation candidate